# Mac installing libraries using the terminal

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, installation, libraries

I have researched this and found answers on SO on this topic yet remain confused.

Trying to get started with Git. I'm new to shell scripting too so hopefully after this I'll be more familiar with it.

I'm reading this page about how to get up and running with Git: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

I created a directory on my desktop called "git" and navigated to it in the terminal. With my level of experience in shell scripting this was a victory. Then, following a blog post on how to download fromt he terminal ran this command:

```
curl -O http://git-scm.com/download
```

That worked, or at least a new file was added to the "git" directory that I created.

Reading down the instructions one is told that "To install Git, you need to have the following libraries that Git depends on: curl, zlib, openssl, expat, and libiconv"

OK. Um. How? I did read some blog posts and SO answers on how to do this but failed. The first one for example - type zlib and hit enter - command not found? How do I either check if it's already installed or how do I install it? What about the others?

I tried following this blog post: http://www.neuraladvance.com/using-open-source-libraries-on-mac-os-x.html

I typed:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Wasn't even sure what to expect. The first two commands said not found the last one asked me for a password.

I then tried `./configure --help`

Was then told "No such file or directory"

Needless to say I don't know what to do next. How do I install the libraries on a Mac using the terminal? curl, zlib, openssl, expat, and libiconv

Comment: do you have Xcode installed on your machine?  if so, do you have the "Xcode command line tools" installed with them?  if so, you probably already have git installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure all those libraries are preinstalled on your Mac.
If not, installing Xcode (free on the AppStore) would do the trick.
Xcode actually comes with git (but not the latest version) so if you install Xcode you don't need to install git separately.

To answer your question more generally, you might want to install [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/).
It's a command line tool to install software and libraries and it's pretty easy to use.

It's great that you are discovering the shell. You should read some tutorials for beginners. If you like it, you will learn very fast and in a few weeks, you will understand exactly why the command you tried didn't work. Have fun learning!

Comment: thanks I'm installing Xcode now and think I'll seriously look into something slightly more formal in shell tutoring, like a book of some sort :-)

Answer (score 1):

As Simon suggested you should install Xcode, however the CLI tools are not installed automatically. They must be downloaded through Xcode's, preferences. In Preferences click the Downloads tab then install next to Command Line Tools.

If any of the required tools are not automatically installed with Xcode, [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) is a great, easy to use, utility that can install nearly any UNIX or Linux command with the following syntax:

```
brew install <SomeAppName>
```

The [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) website has easy to follow instructions for setting it up initially. So if anything you need is missing try using that.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 5, to download Command Line Tools, choose Open Developer Tool under "Xcode", then More Developer Tools> from the sub Menu. This takes you to an Apple web page - you'll need a Developer username/password to get to the Downloads page. 
Choose the right CLT for your system, download and install from the dmg/pkg.